# Ext.grid.ColumnModel is not a constructor

Tags: extjs4

I am quite new to extjs..and I installed ext js4 in my server. I get the following error. Not sure what it means:

```
Ext.grid.ColumnModel is not a constructor
```

here 's my link:
http://srikanthrajan.com/test/index.html

Now I get Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel is not a constructor

Basically I am trying the following tutorial:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/ext-js-grids-with-php-and-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the columns for PresidentsColumnModel should be `Ext.grid.column.Column`, not `Ext.grid.ColumnModel`

Comment: Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel is not a constructor ..this is what I get now.can u see the edit to my question

Comment: You should have the ExtJS 4 API to reference, so it can help you not cost much time. Not `Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel`, `Ext.selection.RowModel` should be.

Answer (score 1):

RowModel is default so in your grid configurations try this:

```
selModel: { mode: 'SIMPLE' },
```

or

```
selModel: new Ext.selection.RowModel({singleSelect:false})
```

although singleSelect is not a config option of RowModel, so try:

```
selModel: new Ext.selection.RowModel({model:SIMPLE})
```

From ExtJs docs:

> mode : String
>   Mode of selection. Valid values are:
>
> SINGLE - Only allows selecting one item at a time. Use allowDeselect to allow deselecting >that item. This is the default.
>
> SIMPLE - Allows simple selection of multiple items one-by-one. Each click in grid will >either select or deselect an item.
>
> MULTI - Allows complex selection of multiple items using Ctrl and Shift keys.

EDIT:

I looked at the code in the tutorial you mentioned and noticed that it is for ExtJs 2.x and 3.x versions. Grid changed a lot from version 3 to 4. If you want to follow that tutorial you will need to have ExtJs 4 documentation at hand.